# Java Stream counting Operation until An integer becomes 0

Tags: java, java-stream

How do I use Java Stream given an integer N of which actions are, if N is odd, subtract 1 from it and if N is even, divide it by 2 until N becomes 0?

This is my working code using procedural style:

```
public static int solution(int num) {
    int counter = 0;
    while(num != 0) {
        num = (num % 2 == 0) ? num / 2 : num - 1;
        counter++;
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `IntStream.iterate` with the same logic:

```
public static long solutionStream(int num) {
    return IntStream.iterate(num, i -> i % 2 == 0 ? i / 2 : i -1)
            .takeWhile(i -> i > 0)
            .count();
}
```

Just note that `takeWhile` is only available in Java 9+, and it's necessary here to end the infinite stream produced by `iterate`.

Comment: While using Java9 and above, [one shall not need `takeWhile` for this either.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53348666/1746118).

Comment: @nullpointer great! `takeWhile` came more naturally to me. Thanks.

Comment: @ernest_k Thank you. This is awesome!

Comment: Or `return num == 0? 0: 31-Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(num)+Integer.bitCount(num);`…

Comment: @Holger gorgeous!

Comment: @Holger I'm amazed with your solution but I fail to understand how it works. Could you explain? Thank you.

Comment: @JulezJupiter perhaps it helps when you take the solution of this answer and insert a `.peek(i -> System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i)))` right before the `takeWhile` step and play around with some numbers. Key points: for a positive integer, `i / 2` shifts one bit to the right, resp. cuts the lowest bit off; for an odd number, `i - 1` changes its lowest bit from `1` to `0`. Consider what happens when you do this repeatedly and what you’re basically counting (on the bit level).

Answer (score 3):

With Java9+ an [alternative to ernest's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53348642/1746118) could be using `IntStream iterate(int seed, IntPredicate hasNext, IntUnaryOperator next)` could be as follows :

```
public static int solution(int num) {
    return (int) IntStream.iterate(num, i -> i > 0, i -> i % 2 == 0 ? i / 2 : i - 1).count();
}
```

Comment: Your solution works like charm. It is shorter. However, I had to accept ernest_k's answer as I find it more readable.